# Elasticsearch 7: Cant parse date

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, date-formatting

I have an elasticsearch index with a mapping that has a date field

```
"datetime": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "date_optional_time"
            }
```

but when i try to pass in

`'05/09/2019 11:43:09 AM'`

and index it, i get

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u"failed to parse field [datetime] of type [date] in document with id 'VhhGBWsBeH-i3pqE8QBW'")
```

i tried

```
"datetime": {
               "type": "text"
            }
```

and this works of course.

What am i doing wrong? Which date format should i use for dates like `05/09/2019 11:43:09 AM`?

@Kamal

Thanks a lot for your help. just one more thing, the above format fails for `'05/09/2019 01:00:37 PM'` or for any value with `PM`. i tried

```
"datetime": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a||MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss p"
            }
```

but i get

`"Invalid format: [MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss p]: Pad letter 'p' must be followed by valid pad pattern: MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss p"`

if i try

```
"datetime": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa"
            }
```

i get

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, u'illegal_argument_exception', u'Invalid format: [MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa]: Too many pattern letters: a')
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I've replaced **HH** with **hh** and that should give what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the format you've mentioned for your date doesn't adhere to the `date_optional_time`, which is based on ISO 8601 standards.

From the [elasticsearch link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) related to `date_optional_time`, it mentions the below comment:

> *date_optional_time* or *strict_date_optional_time*
>
> A generic ISO datetime parser where the date is mandatory and the time is optional.

Based on ISO 8601, below are some of the valid values:

- **`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`**
- **`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm`**
- **`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS`**.

*Also note that ISO 8601 **uses 24 hours date format**.*

So looking at your sample, the below date value would work for this.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_doc/1
{
  "datetime": "2019-05-09T13:30:00"
}
```

### Solution:

The format you are looking for is **`MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a`** OR **`dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a`** (I leave it to you based on your requirements both formats would work).

Below is how your mapping would be.

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "properties":{  
         "datetime":{  
            "type":"date",
            "format":"date_optional_time||MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The below would now work:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_doc/1
{
  "datetime": "05/09/2019 11:43:09 AM"
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! please see my update in the post. the format works for AM but not for PM for some reason

Comment: Could you try with `"format": "date_optional_time||MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"` (Note **hh** instead of **HH**). I've corrected my answer!!